# Django: Need help returning 2 sets of data in the same view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to return 2 different sets of data in the same view.

The two tables (I've cut out the other attributes to lessen the code):

1. Restaurant
2. Foods

Models

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):

    PRICING = (
        ("£", "£"),
        ("££", "££"),
        ("£££", "£££"),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, choices=PRICING)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Foods(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description  = models.TextField(null=True)
    restaurant   = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image        = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="food_images/")
    price        = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

On this view, I'm trying to list the restaurant data as well as the food data. But how do I access the food data for that specific restaurant?

Views

```
def restaurantDetailView(request, slug):
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(slug=slug)

    context = {
        "restaurant": restaurant,
    }

    return render(request, "restaurants/restaurant_detail.html", context)
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="container restaurant-container" padding-top="40px">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background: #868e96;">
                <img src="{{ restaurant.image.url }}" width="500px" class="card-img-top h-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:28px;">{{restaurant.name}}</h5>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="card-text">{{restaurant.description}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{restaurant.category.all|join:" | " }}</p>
                    <div class="row" style="padding:10px 0px 10px;">
                        <div class="col">Price: {{restaurant.price}}</div>
                        <div class="col">Location:  {{ restaurant.postcode }} | {{ restaurant.city }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding:10px 0px 10px;">
                        <div class="col">Avg Wait: {{restaurant.min_serve_time}} mins</div>
                        <div class="col">Minimum Order: £{{restaurant.min_order_tk}}0</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Image here">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Food data goes here</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Food data here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces this in the frontend.
[image]

Sorry for the long post. Still new to using StackOverflow.

Comment: Just need help with writing the views the not entire frontend part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you can fetch related data in this case with `Food.objects.filter(restaurant=restaurant)`, which will return a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) of `Food` objects that belong to the requested restaurant. Include this `QuerySet` in your `context` dictionary. Then in your template you'll do some kind of for loop referencing that key from the context dictionary.

Overall, your view will look something like:

```py
def restaurantDetailView(request, slug):
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(slug=slug)
    food = Food.objects.filter(restaurant=restaurant)

    context = {
        "restaurant": restaurant,
        "food": food,
    }

    return render(request, "restaurants/restaurant_detail.html", context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this in your template code (simplified):

```
<h1>
  Restaurant name is: {{ restaurant.name }}
</h1>
<h1>Food List:</h1>
{% for food in restaurant.food_set.all %}
  <p>{{ food.name }}: {{ food.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just posted an answer that takes the approach of querying the Food objects in the view, but here you've done it in the template. I'm new to Django, relative to your level of experience - is there a difference between accessing the Food objects in the view vs in the template?

Comment: There is no difference for what the OP is trying to do. Using the relation (`restaurant.food_set.all`) feels more readable to me than a generic `.filter()` expression but this might be personal taste.

Comment: I'm more familiar with using the views method. But very handy to know that the jinja templates are a lot more flexible.

Comment: This is not a template trick, by the way. You could have used it in your answer as well (i.e. `food = restaurant.food_set.all()`).

Comment: Is using `classname_set` to access a related set of objects for `Classname` something that's implicitly defined in Django? Where can I read more about this feature?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/